# How else can I update a custom function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried a lot of things. So far this is the best way for me. It works, but it still bugs me.

I have a custom function that searches for a price based on the name given.
The dummy param doesn't do anything in the custom function.

The spreadsheet updates the custom function as soon as the price values in the database called "Prices" are changed. cuz of the dummy.

Here is how I run the custom function in a cell

```
=searchPrice(B9,Prices!D:D)
```

The problem is this way it checks the whole column in "Prices" and it updates/Loads all the cells/custom function. Is there any other way I could update the custom function so it changes the value for each cell?

In other words, I don't want to look at the whole column. I want to look at a specific column and if it changes then update.

```
//Search Price sheet with the given name. Return price. dummy param updates google ss once the "Prices" sheet values changed.
function searchPrice(name,dummy)
{
  var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Prices";
  var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 2;//Column with Names
  var RETURN_COL_IDX = 3;//Column with prices
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  {
    var col = values[i];
    if (col[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == name)
    {
      return col[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it only returned a price once please? Did it only work once or it is always returning only one price? Also - is the returned value an array or a string?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was thinking about the previous way. (Without the dummy param) It only returned once. Will edit it out.

Comment: and the return value is a string

Comment: Will try it out, had no idea about that build in function.

Comment: Yes VLOOKUP works perfectly and it updates. Thank you this is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom function  is essentially replicating the inbuilt function `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B9,Prices!C:D,2,0)
```

If you have a list of names in B9:B15, use the ARRAY version:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B9:B15,Prices!C:D,2,0))
```